# Fix Screen Resolution for Centos 6 in VMWARE

Tags: centos, screen, vmware, resolution

How can I fix the screen resolution for centos (6.5 or 6.6) in vmware workstation or vmware player?

Answer (score 1):

This works for VMWARE running in both a Windows 7 and centos 6.5/6.6 enviroments.

This was a problem I ran into with centos 6.5 and centos 6.6 on vmware workstation and vmware player(7.0.0 build-2305329). In the display section I can't select a display resolution that is suitable for my monitor. Simple remove (you might want to back up this file but I think it is unnecessary) this file

```
/etc/X11/xorg.con
```

as a root user. Like so

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.con
```

Then restart your system. Now in the top bar (menu bar) on your desktop, go to system, preferences, display.

In the display section you can now choice what ever resolution you like.